# Acceder a propiedad de un objeto dinámicamente

Tags: php, laravel, bucle-for

Estoy trabajando con Laravel, y los datos que estoy recibiendo por request son una colección y vienen en forma de objeto por lo que quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de acceder a la propiedad de un objecto dinámicamente, es decir, generar una cadena que represente el nombre de la propiedad a la que quiero acceder pero cambiando el final de la misma aumentando el valor mediante un ciclo `for`, y luego utilizar esa cadena para obtener los distintos valores de cada propiedad del objeto, para después insertarlos a mi base de datos.

Este es el array del request con los valores que quiero trabajar los cuales representan valores de inputs:

```
array:17 [
  "_token" => "8Js6c825vO45deiJH06EosWAT10QpWcndaBQEzm4"
  "provider_id" => "2"
  "product_name" => "Pro"
  "description" => "Oferta"
  "referencial_value" => "2000"
  "tipo_comision_colocacion" => "si"
  "tipo_comision_recaudo" => "si"
  "nivel" => "4"
  "monto_colocacion1" => "20"
  "monto_colocacion2" => "15"
  "monto_colocacion3" => "10"
  "monto_colocacion4" => "5"
  "monto_recaudo1" => "10"
  "monto_recaudo2" => "7"
  "monto_recaudo3" => "5"
  "monto_recaudo4" => "3"
  "calculo_recaudo" => "%"
]
```

Como pueden ver tengo 4 inputs con nombres similares en donde solo cambia el último número del nombre: `"monto_colocacionX"` donde `X` va desde el 1 hasta el 4.

Intenté hacer un loop donde se incremente un número para agregarlo a la variable que estoy recibiendo y así obtener los datos de los 4 nombres de los inputs.

Esto fue lo que imaginé que podría hacer:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $request->nivel; $i++) {
        $monto_colocacion = $request->monto_colocacion.$i;
        var_dump($monto_colocacion);
    }
}
```

Pero solo obtengo los valores de `$i`

```
string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3" string(1) "4"
```

Pensé que concatenando `$i` con la variable del objeto obtendría el valor de mi input pero no funcionó.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por Responder, lo que pasa es que estoy trabajando con Laravel, y los datos que estoy recibiendo por Request son una colleccion y vienen en manera de Objeto, intente  hacerlo como me dijiste, pero llega Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis que intentas utilizar no funciona debido a que el operador `->` no funciona así. Prueba con:

```php
$monto_colocacion = $request["${monto_colocacion$i}"]
```

Si quieres mantener el operador `->` entonces puedes intentar algo así:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $request->nivel; $i++) {
        $key = "${monto_colocacion$i}";
        $monto_colocacion = $request->$key;
        var_dump($monto_colocacion);
    }
}
```

Revisa el [primer comentario](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php#46290) de la sección de **Classes and Objects** en el que se exponen más ejemplos similares a lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Muchas Gracias seguí tu consejo y modificando  las llaves me funciono perfecta mente 
el código quedo a si 

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $request->nivel; $i++) {
            $key = "monto_colocacion".$i;
            $monto_colocacion = $request->$key;
            var_dump($monto_colocacion);
        }